# what should the size of character be for int to string, FORTRAN

Tags: fortran

The program below errors out at runtime

```
    program exmple
    implicit none
    character(len=10)::FT

    write(FT,*)int(0.75*100)

    end
```

This gives the error

> output statement overflows record, unit -5, file Internal List-Directed Write

In order to remove the error I need len=12 or greater. My question is simply why? What determines the length necessary for an int to string?

In case it is useful I am compiling with ifort v 14.0.2

Comment: This is up to the individual compiler.  If you want to avoid that, you use an explicit format e.g. write(FT,'(I10)'),int(....)

Comment: While concurring with @tim18, default-integer is almost certainly 32 bits including sign; the extreme values of such an integer need 10 decimal digits plus sign, and though I don't know ifort specifically list-directed formatting often outputs a space at the beginning of each record because historically many Fortran processors used/reserved the first character of each record for carriage control. **10+1+1=12.**

Comment: @dave_thompson_085, ifort should place that initial space: it is required by the standard.

Comment: @francescalus Oh for goodness sake, this is not a duplicate of either of the questions linked. Please remove the hold so that an answer can be given.

Comment: @user5713492, please explain why you think the question is not related to those to which I link.  Even if you can't convince me, others are quite welcome to vote to reopen.

Comment: @francescalus I will explain it in my answer. Thanks in advance for reopening.

Comment: @user5713492, I've reviewed my reasoning for closing the question and I still think it was a reasonable decision, but one I'm amenable to reversing.  It's hard to discuss in comments, so perhaps you would like to ask a question on Meta about it?  There you'll get the attention of people who can reopen (even single-handedly), you could convince me I'm wrong, or possibly we could arrange for at least one of those questions be closed as duplicate of this (re-opened) one.  If you do ask a Meta question I'll attempt to explain my thoughts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to section 10.10.4 (List-directed output), Note 10.33 of the Fortran 2008 standard, when the format is not specified

> The length of the output records is not specified and is processor dependent.

This concerns both external and internal files.

I suggest using `'(i0)'` as the format when writing an integer to a string in such conditions: according to the standard, section 10.7.2.1, paragraph 1 (5),

> On output, with I, B, O, Z, F, and G editing, the specified value of the field width *w* may be zero.  In such cases, the processor selects the smallest positive actual field width that does not result in a field filled with asterisks.

Answer (score 1):

> What determines the length necessary for an int to string?

If you are not specifying a format, it is compiler-dependent. To know for your specific compiler, just do a print and check the output (in my ifort 18 it is 12 too).

Anyway, you shouldn't count in this behavior because it wont be portable at all. If posible, use a formated output.

**EDIT**: Just a hint on how the compilers choose the length of a unformatted integer. The maximum representable integral number by a default integer (usually 4 bytes) is `2^31 - 1 = 2147483647` and this is a 10 digits number. Add one more character for a posible minus singal, and one space for separating it from the previous record, you get 12.